# Rails Minitest for polymorphism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

A class was generated with `associable:references{polymorphic}`
Thus the schema has:

```
    t.string "associable_type", null: false
    t.bigint "associable_id", null: false
```

The fixtures auto-generated by rails have:

```
  associable: one
  associable_type: Associable
```

There was an attempt to modify the fixtures to reflect the schema:

```
  associable_id: 4
  associable_type: Chain
```

The following test

```
  test "valid " do
    contact = Contact.new(associable_id: 2, associable_type: 'User')
puts contact.valid?
puts contact.errors.inspect
    assert contact.valid?
  end
```

returns

```
false
#<ActiveModel::Errors [#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=associable, type=blank, options={:message=>:required}>]>
```

Changing the test to `contact = Contact.new(associable: two, associable_type: 'User')`
complains with `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'two'` as per the autogenerated syntax

How can polymorphic records be properly tested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixtures are data which are created and that you can test against. We can refer https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html for detail understanding. In our case we don't need to modify the fixtures.

The error which we are getting in our test case is because we haven't created record in **users** table. So when it tries to validate the record it check whether the record with mentioned id `associable_id: 2` (i.e 2 in our case) is present in users table or not.

You can modify test case as below

```
test "valid " do
  user = User.new(name: 'Jerome', email: 'jerome@gmail.com')
  user.save
  Contact.new(associable: user)
  puts contact.valid?
  puts contact.errors.inspect
  assert contact.valid?
end
```

Note: I haven't add other columns as i am not aware of your users and contacts schema. Please add columns if there are any.